How do i get Nifty 50 EPS value for a certain date in Google Sheets?
I am using this formula to get the Price
=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50","price", [Date])

however, when i change the parameter to eps, its showing #NA
=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50","eps", [Date])

Please help

NIFTY_50 EPS is not Supported in Google finance
Upon checking supported attributes for the tickler NIFTY_50, "EPS" is not part of it.
I have checked it using the formula.
=GOOGLEFINANCE("INDEXNSE:NIFTY_50","all", "DATE")

Moreover, index funds don't have valid points of reference or doesn't have earnings for an EPS.
For the formula of EPS, it requires outstanding shares, as NIFTY_50 is an OPEN ENDED Mutual Fund it doesn't have one which renders the attribute being requested to be a moot.

If you need more questions about the financial math of things I would suggest also posting to another StackExchange  Forum

You can also read about this in this post: eps-for-a-market-in-google-sheets.

You can also read more information here: price-earningsratio.asp


Note: the given formula is not the expected result but you may use it in case  you encounter this problem on a different ticker in the near future.
Sample Output


Hi @Sam K, was the answer above able to fix your issue?
Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you

In the reference documentation for the GOOGLEFINANCE function you will see that price is only a valid attribute for realtime data while eps is only a valid attribute for historical data.
I think that you didn't specify the full formula in your question, that [Date] part is probably not there in your call so you try to receive real-time data.
Also the documentation mentions that

Some attributes may not yield results for all symbols.

